# Hieroglyphic from Herschel to Babbage?

Tags: functions, puzzle, math-history

**EDIT:**

I have also posted this on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36836/this-image-contains-a-great-discovery) which should be a better fit.

John Herschel sent a letter to Charles Babbage in which he included this hieroglyphic with the message "Interpret it, it contains a great discovery". Personally I have no clue what it could mean.

[image]

The figure at the centre is described as: "Dionysius the God of Functions, alias the genius of numerical magnitude."

I didn't know what to tag this, please feel free to improve the tagging.

More pictures can be found here: http://www.bradyharanblog.com/blog/2015/7/10/herschels-mysterious-doodle-1

And a video on it can be found here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn-0zSuAWpI